Как разбить строку без пробелов и каждый символ поместить в список?
пример: на входе 01000 -- на выходе [0, 1, 0, 0, 0] ( можно так ['0', '1', '0', '0', '0']
пример2: на входе 11110 -- на выходе [1, 1, 1, 1, 0]

list(string). А может, вам и вообще список не нужен - обойдёте символы строки, да и всё? Это зависит от задачи, которую вы пока не описали

list(s) - превратит строку в символы. list(str(i)) - превратит число в цифры. list(map(int, str(i))) - превратит число в значения цифр.

s = '010010'

res1 = list(s)
res2 = list(map(int, s))
res3 = [int(c) for c in s]


Превращаем строку в список, список с строками. (['0', '1', ...])
С помощью map каждый элемент представляем в виде числа и, так как map это итератор, используем list. ([0, 1, ...])
Сразу строим список, вручную перебирая строку. ([0, 1, ...])


string = "1010101120"
string_end = []

for x in string :
    string_end.append("`" + str(x) + "`")


пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]
